# any site for blogger / blogspot questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a StackExchange site where blogger.com / blogspot.com questions are appropriate?

Hmm, I'm getting the "quality standards" error.  What part of the question would set that off?

Comment: The "quality standards" warning in this case was probably due to the length of the question.

Comment: This question is a bit ambiguous to me. Is it asking how to ask about code (or something topical) posted on blogger/blogspot/etc or about _using_ blogger/blogspot/etc itself? Refusing to own a blog likely leaves me in the minority but when helping people with blogs I was left with the impression that they typically involve HTML of some sort. If that's true, wouldn't SO be the place to ask those sort of questions (after proper research of course)?

Comment: @M.Babcock, blogger does a great job of hiding coding and html from the user.  You can look at my blogger-hosted blog for an example of what can be done with almost zero configuration:  http://eastbay-rc.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like both [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogger) and [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogger) accept questions about Blogger.